# Find indices of elements that match condition of 2D array by row

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2D array with floats called A of dimensions n x m. And I have a 1D array of floats of dimension n called B. For each row i in A I want to find the indices of values that are smaller than the ith value in B

I tried to use np.argwhere

`A = np.array([[.1,.2,.3,.4], [.1,.2,.3,.4], [.1,.2,.3,.4]])
B = np.array([0.15, 0.25, 0.35])
np.argwhere(A.T < B)`

This is the output

`array([[0, 0],[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 1],[1, 2],[2, 2]])`

I would like to have is something like this

`[array([0,1,2]), array([1,2]), array([2])]`

And, of course, I would like it to be vectorized and not looped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.where` + `np.split`

```
x, y = np.where(A.T < B)

s = np.flatnonzero(np.append([False], x[1:] != x[:-1]))

np.split(y, s)
```

```
[array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([2], dtype=int64)]
```